# Adding Points to a PathFigure (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

I simply want to add a custom new point to a PathFigure in c#-code. I'm a bit overwhelmed with that intricate Path-stuff.

Comment: You need to copy the code you have so far and paste it into the question. Copy it as text, not as a screenshot. Make sure it's entirely indented by at least four spaces, so Stack Overflow will format it as code. If it's not indented right, select the whole block of code and press Ctrl+K.

Comment: I didnt think that the code was relevant here

Comment: You were wrong.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to draw a straight line from point to point you can do the following.

```
<Path Stroke="Black" Data="M 10,10 L 5,100 50,10 70,0" />
```

- The M is the absolute `moveto` command. It starts a new sub-path with the given cordinate.
- L stands for the absolute `lineto` command. It draws a line from the current point to the given cordinate which becomes the new current point.

This means we start drawing at (10,10) then move to (5,100) then to (50,10) and finally to (70,0). Thease are all absolute cordinates.

[image]

---

There are many more possibilities to draw a path as documented [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataLinetoCommands).

Generally they are seperated into the following categories.

- moveto
- lineto
- curve
- closepath
- ...

**moveto**

- M (absolute)
- m (relative)

> moveto (x y)+  Start a new sub-path at the given (x,y) coordinate. M (uppercase) indicates that absolute coordinates will follow; m (lowercase) indicates that relative coordinates will follow. If a moveto is followed by multiple pairs of coordinates, the subsequent pairs are treated as implicit lineto commands. Hence, implicit lineto commands will be relative if the moveto is relative, and absolute if the moveto is absolute. If a relative moveto (m) appears as the first element of the path, then it is treated as a pair of absolute coordinates. In this case, subsequent pairs of coordinates are treated as relative even though the initial moveto is interpreted as an absolute moveto.

*Example*

```
<Path Stroke="Black" Data="M 10,10" />
<Path Stroke="Black" Data="m 10,10" />
```

---

**lineto**

The various "lineto" commands draw straight lines from the current point to a new point.

- L (absolute)
- l (relative)

> Draw a line from the current point to the given (x,y) coordinate which becomes the new current point. L (uppercase) indicates that absolute coordinates will follow; l (lowercase) indicates that relative coordinates will follow. A number of coordinates pairs may be specified to draw a polyline. At the end of the command, the new current point is set to the final set of coordinates provided.

*Example*

```
<Path Stroke="Black" Data="M 10,10 L 20,20 M 10,10 L 30,10" />
```

[image]

---

- H (absolute)
- h (relative)

> Draws a horizontal line from the current point (cpx, cpy) to (x, cpy). H (uppercase) indicates that absolute coordinates will follow; h (lowercase) indicates that relative coordinates will follow. Multiple x values can be provided (although usually this doesn't make sense). At the end of the command, the new current point becomes (x, cpy) for the final value of x.

*Example*

```
<Path Stroke="Black" Data="M 10,10 H 60" />
```

[image]

---

- V (absolute)
- v (relative)

> Draws a vertical line from the current point (cpx, cpy) to (cpx, y). V (uppercase) indicates that absolute coordinates will follow; v (lowercase) indicates that relative coordinates will follow. Multiple y values can be provided (although usually this doesn't make sense). At the end of the command, the new current point becomes (cpx, y) for the final value of y.

*Example*

```
<Path Stroke="Black" Data="M 10,10 V 60" />
```

[image]

---

et cetera

---

To change the paths geometry in the code behind you can do this.

```
var path = MyPathElement.Data.GetFlattenedPathGeometry();
path.AddGeometry(new EllipseGeometry(new Point(200, 200), 20, 30));
path.AddGeometry(new LineGeometry(new Point(0, 0), new Point(10, 500)));
MyPathElement.Data = path;
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed awnser. But what about dynamic assigning in c# code?

Comment: @Jan I've added a sample at the end of the answer

Comment: @NtFrex Thank you :)

Comment: @Jan You should mark this as the accepted answer.